# Remove HTTPS if the url is a subdomain (.htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to know how to add a condition that if the url is a subdomain, then ignore the "Force" https condition

Here the .htaccess that add the force HTTPS

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `RewriteCond` in your htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this before the last line

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(example\.com|www) [NC]
```